# Ask About ExpectedConditions

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
   public static IWebElement WaitGetElement(IWebDriver driver, By by, int timeoutInSeconds, bool checkIsVisible = false)
    {
        WebDriverWait webDriverWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds((double)timeoutInSeconds));
        IWebElement result;
        try
        {
            if (checkIsVisible)
            {
                result = webDriverWait.Until<IWebElement>(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(by));
            }
            else
            {
                result = webDriverWait.Until<IWebElement>(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(by));
            }
        }
        catch (NoSuchElementException)
        {
            result = null;
        }
        catch (WebDriverTimeoutException)
        {
            result = null;
        }
        catch (TimeoutException)
        {
            result = null;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

This is My Code . It Give Me Erro : The name 'ExpectedConditions' does not exist in the current context .
Can you Help Me .

Comment: Please don't put tags in your question titles. The tagging help page explicitly warns against it.

Comment: Oh oke  i dont know that

Comment: Click "ExpectedConditions", press `Ctrl` + `.`, does it show a prompt to add a `using`?

Comment: Nope :V it generate new class or porperty .... etc

Comment: It looks like you're probably missing a package then. Hopefully someone experienced with Selenium can tell you which one :)

Answer (score 2):

I Think you are missing this particular Nuget package "SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions" 
https://www.nuget.org/packages/DotNetSeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers/3.11.0

You can download it from nuget library or with the link provided. Later as some comments tell you must put an "using" in the code.

I hope this helps

Comment: Ok Thanks :D a lot